# FTP connect in Bluemix PHP

Tags: php, ftp, ibm-cloud

I came to an understanding that FTP connect or any FTP related methods will not work in Bluemix. Is there any twerk or any method that i should include or prefer to make my php application work in Bluemix.

If that is not possible, is there any other service providers like Bluemix that i can use to host my php application ?

Answer (score 0):

for outcoming communication on port: 21 you shouldn't have any issues in Bluemix. It is opened. Instead, all incoming communication on ftp port are blocked. (you can only use http and https port)

Bluemix is a platform as a service (PaaS) based on the Cloud Foundry. It makes no sense to enable the port 21 for incoming traffic. And it should be the same for other platform as a service based on CF.

Comment: So what should i do now ? How would i execute my ftp commands like ftp_connect and ftp_put in that php application.

Comment: As Crescenzo said, if it is the PhP app which wants to open FTP connection with external sites you can do it. What you can't do is to execute FTP against Bluemix itself.